# Drawing Semi-Circles in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Is there a way to draw a semicircle in Pygame? Something like this:

[image: semicircle]

`pygame.surface.set_clip()` will not work for this - I need circles that look like pie slices as well, like this one:

[image: pie slice]

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I edited the question "to explain how it is different". Could you open it?

Comment: What about a fine polygon? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246185/python-draw-pie-shapes-with-colour-filled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyGame` has no function to create filled `arc/pie` but you can use `PIL/pillow` to generate bitmap with `pieslice` and convert to `PyGame` image to display it.

```
import pygame
#import pygame.gfxdraw
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREY  = (128, 128, 128)

#PI = 3.1415

# --- main ----

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# - generate PIL image with transparent background -

pil_size = 300

pil_image = Image.new("RGBA", (pil_size, pil_size))
pil_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
#pil_draw.arc((0, 0, pil_size-1, pil_size-1), 0, 270, fill=RED)
pil_draw.pieslice((0, 0, pil_size-1, pil_size-1), 330, 0, fill=GREY)

# - convert into PyGame image -

mode = pil_image.mode
size = pil_image.size
data = pil_image.tobytes()

image = pygame.image.fromstring(data, size, mode)

image_rect = image.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    #pygame.draw.arc(screen, BLACK, (300, 200, 200, 200), 0, PI/2, 1)
    #pygame.gfxdraw.pie(screen, 400, 300, 100, 0, 90, RED)
    #pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, 400, 300, 100, 90, 180, GREEN)

    screen.blit(image, image_rect) # <- display image

    pygame.display.flip()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Result:

[image]

GitHub: [furas/python-examples/pygame/pillow-image-pieslice](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/pillow-image-pieslice)

Answer (score 3):

```
import pygame
from math import sin,cos,radians

#function to draw pie using parametric coordinates of circle
def pie(scr,color,center,radius,start_angle,stop_angle):
    theta=start_angle
    while theta <= stop_angle:
        pygame.draw.line(scr,color,center, 
        (center[0]+radius*cos(radians(theta)),center[1]+radius*sin(radians(theta))),2)
        theta+=0.01

#for example:-
if __name__=="__main__":
    winWidth,winHeight=500,500
    scr=pygame.display.set_mode((winWidth,winHeight))
    pie(scr,(255,0,0),(winWidth//2,winHeight//2),250,0,60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[this is result of this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCJ6D.png)

The way this code solves the issue is by rotating a line of width 2 around a circle so that the overlap between any two lines doesn't leave a gap

The real life analogy would be to think about a thick clock hand moving around a clock and taking pictures of it so that when you overlay the images you get a filled in sector of a circle.

Comment: Code only answers may provide the solution, but they lack the ability to give in depth detail about the solution. Always explain what and how your code solves OP's problem.